# Azure Storage Explorer vs PowerShell ISE (different outcomes)

Tags: azure, blob, storage, azure-powershell

I want to use a standard script for creating directories in a storage container (ADLS Gen2). I can create this directory using Storage Explorer currently. My current role assignment are Contributor and Reader.

When I attempt to do the same using a powershell script, I get the 403 error.
Based on reading, I know that I need the role Storage Blob Data Contributor to perform this action.

What perplexes me is why I am able to do this operation using Azure Storage Explorer but not using a script. For both, I authenticate using SSO

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility of using PowerShell commands with storage explorer as it is a third-party tool works with storage resources only.

To create a directory file share in a storage account container, use
[`New-AzStorageDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragedirectory?view=azps-11.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.4.0) command as detailed below.

```
$storageAccount = "xxx"
$resourceGroup = "xxx"
$container = "new"
$directory = "xxxx"
$Account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storage Account
$AccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $Account)[0].Value
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $Account -StorageAccountKey $AccountKey
New-AzStorageDirectory -ShareName "jahShare06" -Context $storageContext -Path $directory
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running the script using Window ISE app. I have a script that works in another container because I have Storage Blob Data Contributor in that container. What confounds me is that I am able to create directory on this container when using Azure Storage Explorer but get a permission error when running the script in Window ISE app

Comment: What is the error message? Can you paste it here! @SwatiVishwanathan

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took time to comment on this post!
I have made some embarrassing discovery. When connecting to the blob container, I was actually setting up the connection at the account level. So when I was performing these actions in the Explorer, the context was different that the context I provided in the Powershell script.

Comment: Now did u able to resolve the issue or what is the issue you are facing? @SwatiVishwanathan